# My front door frame doesn't support installing a storm door

Tags: doors

Please see attached picture. Notice that there isn't any brick molding at the top of the door frame and the jam is not deep enough space to mount a door closer on. What are my options ? are there jamb extension kits simple enough for DIY ?[image: Front door]

Comment: Are there jamb extension kits simple enough to DiY and will match the fit-and-finish of the absolutely beautiful exterior of your home? No. - Can I break into your house with my fist? Yes. Solve that problem (windows next to the door knob) and the solution will present itself.

Comment: You need a sheet metal break, custom cut lumber, and an attention to detail that's nigh impossible to achieve ad hoc, whether or not you have +30y experience.

Comment: The other option is a ~4', $4k screen door that spans the whole opening, which will make your house look like a prison. I up-voted, hoping someone would lay it out for you. But the lack of response mirrors my enthusiasm of having to do this job.

Comment: Why do you want a storm door?   For What It's Worth (which may be very little) a contractor/inspector who I respect told me that from an energy perspective, a high quality modern door (which you appear to have) provides better insulation than a crappy older one with a storm door.  You may not need one, unless you want to leave your door wide open to *see* through the storm door even though you have those windows.  Which appear to be double glazed.  You seem to be in good shape.

Answer (score 2):

install a brick mold on either side of the door frame and paint to the color of your choice. the brick mold must be flush at the top of the door jam to accept the drip edge from the storm door

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Anything painted would deviate from the low-maintenance state of the home. I'd suggest unpainted white vinyl molding instead. You'll probably need something wider than brick mold, anyway. Looks like a 2-1/2 to 3" offset.

Comment: @isherwood - I don't see this answer or your suggestion working.   Yes good idea normally but not with the side windows.    You could probably get a custom screen door on there as is with exposed hinges... this would look just as good as mold extension... which is not very good.

Comment: I don't see how the windows are relevant. If vinyl boards can be attached to extend the mullions/astragals to flush with the head jamb, a standard storm door could probably be fit. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of a DIY for the same situation.  I bought two 2x4s and will cut them down to fit snugly. I will use picket holes, wood glue and wood filler to make them match and fingers crossed, my storm door will attach!
[image]

Comment: Welcome. While this hints at an answer, it also seems a little like a discussion forum post. Please see [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: What's a "picket hole"? Did you mean _pocket_ hole? How is wood glue going to help bond to painted metal or vinyl?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).